# Java abstract classes and inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

Can someone please take a look at my code and suggest where I wandered off the path of working code.

The assignment reads:
Write an application named UseLoan that uses an abstract class named PersonalLoan and subclasses to display two different types of loans -home and car- and the cost per month for each. Each of the subclasses contains a constructor that sets the cost per month based on the loan type, after prompting the user for at least one data-entry item that is used in the cost-determining decision. (For example, with a car loan, you might ask the age of the car, or whether it is a sports car.) Include an abstract toString() method in the PersonalLoan class that constructs a String containing all the relevant data. Prompt the user for the type of insurance, and then create and display the appropriate object. Save the files as PersonalLoan.java, CarLoan.java, homeLoan.java, and UseLoan.java.

when i compile code i get following error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Cannot instantiate the type CarLoan
    Cannot instantiate the type CarLoan
    Cannot instantiate the type CarLoan
    Cannot instantiate the type CarLoan
    Cannot instantiate the type HomeLoan

```
at UseLoan.main(UseLoan.java:7)
```

My code so far is as follows:

```
public abstract class PersonalLoan {

String title = new String();
double sportsPrice, suvPrice, hybridPrice, pickupPrice, price30, price15, price5;

public PersonalLoan(String t) {
    title = t;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public double getSportsPrice() {
    return sportsPrice;
}

public abstract void setSportsPrice();

public double getSUVPrice() {
    return suvPrice;
}

public abstract void setSUVPrice();

public double getHybridPrice() {
    return hybridPrice;
}

public abstract void setHybridPrice();

public double getPickupPrice() {
    return pickupPrice;
}

public abstract void setPickupPrice();

public double getPrice30() {
    return price30;
}

public abstract void setPrice30();

public double getPrice15() {
    return price15;
}

public abstract void setPrice15();

public double getPrice5() {
    return price5;
}

public abstract void setPrice5();
}
```

here is second subclass PersonalLoan:

```
public class CarLoan extends PersonalLoan {

public CarLoan(String title) {
    super(title);
    setSportsPrice();
    setSUVPrice();
    setHybridPrice();
    setPickupPrice();
}
 public void setSportsPrice() {
    super.sportsPrice = 1.99;
 }

public void setSUVPrice() {
    super.suvPrice = 2.99;
}

public void setHybridPrice() {
    super.hybridPrice = 3.99;
}

public void setPickupPrice() {
    super.pickupPrice = 4.99;
}
}
```

here is class HomeLoan:

```
public class HomeLoan extends PersonalLoan {

public HomeLoan(String title) {
    super(title);
    setPrice30();
    setPrice15();
    setPrice5();
}

public void setPrice30() {
    super.price30 = 1.99;
}

public void setPrice15() {
    super.price15 = 2.99;
}

public void setPrice5() {
    super.price5 = 3.99;
}
}
```

Here is main class UseLoan:

```
public class UseLoan {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    PersonalLoan aPersonalLoan[] = new PersonalLoan[5];
    int x;
    aPersonalLoan[0] = new CarLoan("Sports Car");
    aPersonalLoan[1] = new CarLoan("SUV");
    aPersonalLoan[2] = new CarLoan("Hybrid");
    aPersonalLoan[3] = new CarLoan("Pickup Truck");
    aPersonalLoan[5] = new HomeLoan("30 Year Mortgage");

    for (x = 0; x < aPersonalLoan.length; ++x) {
        System.out.println("Book #" + (x + 1) + ": " + aPersonalLoan[x].getTitle() + " costs $" + aPersonalLoan[x].getSportsPrice());
        //System.out.println("Book #" + (x + 1) + ": " + aPersonalLoan[x].getTitle() + " costs $" + aPersonalLoan[x].getSUVPrice());
        //System.out.println("Book #" + (x + 1) + ": " + aPersonalLoan[x].getTitle() + " costs $" + aPersonalLoan[x].getHybridPrice());
        //System.out.println("Book #" + (x + 1) + ": " + aPersonalLoan[x].getTitle() + " costs $" + aPersonalLoan[x].getPickupPrice());
        //System.out.println("Book #" + (x + 1) + ": " + aPersonalLoan[x].getTitle() + " costs $" + aPersonalLoan[X].getPrice30());
        //System.out.println("Book #" + (x + 1) + ": " + aPersonalLoan[x].getTitle() + " costs $" + aPersonalLoan[X].getPrice15());
        //System.out.println("Book #" + (x + 1) + ": " + aPersonalLoan[x].getTitle() +          " costs $" + aPersonalLoan[X].getPrice5());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you have all those `setPriceX()` methods instead of just `setPrice(int price)`? ([DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic problem from stack trace is CarLoan does not implement `setPrice5()` in `PersonalLoan` class.

But by design your classes is not right

PersonalLoan is loan type independent and hence should not have loan specific info like setSportsPrice, etc

`PersonalLoan` should probably have methods such as 
1) `setLoanAmount()` - abstract,
2) `setLoanAmount()`
3) `setEMI()` - abstract
4) `getEMI()`
which are set in the contructor of your subclasses based on input parameters as mentioned in your assignment statement

```
public HomeLoan(double loanAmount, int loanTenure) {
    super(title);
    setLoanAmount(loanAmount)
    int homeLoanRate = 10;
    double emi = (loanAmount*loanTenure*homeLoanRate)/100; // pls change formula. This is a just a guideline
    setEMI(emi);

}
```

Similarly `CarLoan` should take parameters such as cost of purchase of current owner, age of car, tenure and calculate based on depreciation the current price and hence the emi

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
Uncompilable source code - CarLoan is not abstract and does not override abstract method setPrice5() in PersonalLoan
```

Compiler error message is clear. You haven't provided implementation for `setPrice5()` in `PersonalLoan` class.

Like `setPrice5()` method in `HomeLoan` class, you need to add setPrice5() method to `PersonalLoan` class also.

Comment: @JamesBlent Uh, did you try implimenting the abstract method setPrice5 ?

Comment: carLoan is abstract ...yu can check public abstract CarLoan

Comment: @Keyser there appear red line under  aPersonalLoan[0] = new CarLoan("Sports Car");
    aPersonalLoan[1] = new CarLoan("SUV");
    aPersonalLoan[2] = new CarLoan("Hybrid");
    aPersonalLoan[3] = new CarLoan("Pickup Truck");
    aPersonalLoan[5] = new HomeLoan("30 Year Mortgage");

Comment: @JamesBlent: Compiler errors are different from runtime exceptions. Compiler error (red mark you are seeing) happens if your code violating java language specification.

Comment: Ok then my question is slightly different, why does it say `java.lang.RuntimeException:` when it's a compile error? Note that I'm not the OP.

Comment: Kyeser error is now:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Cannot instantiate the type CarLoan
 Cannot instantiate the type CarLoan
 Cannot instantiate the type CarLoan
 Cannot instantiate the type CarLoan
 Cannot instantiate the type HomeLoan

 at UseLoan.main(UseLoan.java:7)

Comment: @keyser: I see what you mean, I guess it is because classes are not compiled well, but OP tried to run the program (based on  thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError)

Comment: @Nambari That makes sense. And James, when your program doesn't compile it will almost always tell you why. Read the error messages carefully.

Comment: i have updated error and this error is on these lines:   aPersonalLoan[0] = new CarLoan("Sports Car");
        aPersonalLoan[1] = new CarLoan("SUV");
        aPersonalLoan[2] = new CarLoan("Hybrid");
        aPersonalLoan[3] = new CarLoan("Pickup Truck");
        aPersonalLoan[5] = new HomeLoan("30 Year Mortgage");

Comment: @JamesBlent You shouldn't update your question with new errors. And you shouldn't spam Stackoverflow whenever your code doesn't compile :p. And post the _full_ stack trace.

Comment: i am not spamming any one..you can check yourself..please help

Comment: @JamesBlent: all I can tell you is, please do some research (put some effort on reading/googling) instead of simply posting exception. If you spend few minutes, sure you will get answer. I prefer give pointers than full answers.

Comment: @JamesBlent: Have you googled for "Unresolved compilation problems: Cannot instantiate the type ", please try that and see if have answer.